# Video output from Raspberry Pi stops after a while

Tags: raspberry-pi, hdmi

I have a Raspberry Pi without keyboard or mouse, connected to my LG HD TV via HDMI. I control it via SSH from my laptop.

I have noticed for some time that when I turn on the TV or change to the Raspberry Pi input that the screen is black. If I play a movie or startx video appears, but when they end the screen goes black again.

Just now I had started the X server to experiment with something and while I was googling to figure something out and running test programs etc., the screen suddenly went black.

I killed the X server from the SSH session, and the video re-appeared with the remnants of the boot sequence and the console login prompt.

Does anyone have any idea:

- What is happening?
- How can I keep the video visible as long as the TV is set to the relevant HDMI input?
- How can I turn the video on when switching to the relevant HDMI input?
- If 2/3 don't work and the screen goes black, how can I recover it?

Thanks.

Comment: is there a screensaver running, perhaps?

Comment: Is the pi running out of memory?

Comment: maybe something needs to be changed in `/boot/config.txt`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put this in your rc.local and reboot: `sh -c 'setterm -blank 0 -powersave off -powerdown 0 < /dev/console > /dev/console 2>&1'`